# Java List vs Array[]. Previous threads say to use Lists, I'm not convinced.

Tags: java, arrays, list, performance

I've read some previous posts on the matter. The arguments are that lists are easier to use, more flexible.

All of my previous experience has showed me that flexibility comes as a cost.

The program I am designing makes heavy use of lists. I have maps to lists of lists that are compared, and appended, and searched (oh my!).

Its easy to append two lists. listA.appendAll(listB).

Its almost as easy to append two arrays. Simply create an new array the size of both and copy them.

Now, when these operations are being done in order of tens of thousands, my gut is telling me that Arrays will be a considerably better choice. Of course, I'd much rather use a list, but not at the expense of a performance hit

Is my gut instinct correct, or are lists truly as efficient as arrays? I understand how ArrayLists double in capacity to make appending average ~O(N), but I need the most efficient choice for my usage.

Comment: Premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: You mean "make appending average O(**1**)". In any case, it's hard to answer this without knowing the details of your project -- it would be best to time both variants.

Comment: An `ArrayList` (specifically **Array**) is just a `List` implementation backed by an `array`.

Comment: Don't listen to your gut. Use a profiler and measure. Rarely are bottlenecks where you assumed they were.

Comment: The "most" efficient solution? Why are you implementing in such a high level language? Just use C, then you don't even have the ArrayList option.

Comment: @RC. That's .NET, this is Java.

Comment: Why don't you test? Create a list and array and fill them with gibberish. Measure the time for certain actions.

Comment: @arshajii my bad, sorry

Comment: Ignoring performance is the root of all evil.

Comment: It depends on your needs. If you need random inserts or deletes, lists are better. But then again, you'll need to pick the right tool (e.g.: LinkedLists instead of ArrayList). Then benchmark, and if you need to optimize for performance, consider using Guava or Trove.

Answer (score 8):

Your gut instinct is almost always wrong (if you knew for sure, you wouldn't need to listen to your guts and if you don't know, your decision is mostly random).

The question today isn't how efficient lists are, the question is: How much memory do you have to spare and how much time can you allocate to hunt for bugs in your optimized (but sadly slightly broken) code?

Millions of people are using `ArrayList`, it's a safe, proven, fast and reliable technology. Appending two of them is almost as fast as doing it manually with two native arrays but a) it's only a single line of code for *me*, b) it covers all the corner cases and c) if it should really be too slow, I can have my profiler find the few places where it's too slow and fix those (instead of making my life miserable in a thousand places where 999 don't matter much).

In addition to that, since `ArrayList` is such a heavy used type, the Java compilers and JIT have been optimized to death to make them fast. So even when it looks like it was more code, it might be actually faster than anything you can write manually because the JIT won't recognize your code and optimize it as aggressively.

Lastly, you can easily write your own `ArrayList` to use a more efficient allocation algorithm. If you write your code using the `List` interface everywhere, you can end up with something that you need to optimize in a single place only to make it faster everywhere.

Or maybe use a new Array interface with the 2-3 operations that you need. That way, you could easily create 2-3 implementations which different optimization goals and use them accordingly.

From my experience, the worst solution is to sprinkle your code with 4-10 line chunks of native array operations (like the four lines you need to append two arrays). At least move such code in a common helper class and make sure you cover all the corner cases with unit tests.

Answer (score 2):

*Is my gut instinct correct, or are lists truly as efficient as arrays?*
**Neither.**  Lists are not "truly" as efficient as Arrays (although ArrayLists are close), but this doesn't mean that any optimization necessarily outweighs the flexibility benefits, even if you have thousands of operations going on.

Consider these questions:

- Does this application need to be really, really fast?
- Is the part of the code using either Arrays or Lists never going to be further developed?

If the answer to both of these questions is **yes**, then use Arrays.  Otherwise, use Lists.

But since the performance between Arrays and Lists (particularly the ArrayList implementation) isn't that much, and since your code is highly *likely* to be developed further...
...**just use Lists**.

Answer (score 1):

[ArrayList](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.%3Cinit%3E%28int%29) is backed by an array so without testing I feel that they are probably close in efficiency. If you know the size of your arrays just construct `ArrayList` with an initial size to reduce the overhead of increasing the size.

```
  public ArrayList(int initialCapacity) {
     super();
     if (initialCapacity < 0)
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal Capacity: "+ initialCapacity);
     this.elementData = new Object[initialCapacity];
 }
```

`ArrayList.addAll` ArrayList implementation already looks like something you would probably come up with

```
    public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> c) {
     Object[] a = c.toArray();
     int numNew = a.length;
     ensureCapacity(size + numNew);  // Increments modCount
     System.arraycopy(a, 0, elementData, size, numNew);
     size += numNew;
     return numNew != 0;
 }
```

odd are if you make the array yourself you will probably end up making a helper methods to do most of the stuff that `ArrayList` has already implemented. Don't reinvent the wheel